# Facebook Graph API FQL Query Limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there an official limit (or at least a guaranteed rate) for Graph API calls?

I am getting valid access_tokens for users and use them both on web server and client side scripts. Both calls use FQL queries, which are like below:

```
SELECT+page_id+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+uid=me()+and+page_id=...&access_token=...

SELECT+post_id+FROM+stream+WHERE+(privacy.value='EVERYONE'+OR+privacy.value='ALL_FRIENDS')+AND+attachment.description='...'+AND+attachment.name='...'+AND+actor_id=me()+AND+source_id=me()+AND+is_hidden=0&access_token=...
```

I plan to query once every minute for each **access_token** and some will be made from client IPs, some from web server IP. So what exactly must I care?

And one additional question :) about the "me()" in those queries, if I make the calls from client or server does it differ? e.g. if the client user changes his/her FB login out of my web page, does it refer to new login or the login that the access_token had been generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Facebook had app boxes and profile pages, My Countdown app updated the profile once per hour. At one point it had 400K users, thus was making 9.6 million (400K x 24) calls to Facebook per day.

I'm not sure if there is a limit, but the subscribe feature is suppose eliminate the need to hit their API so often. It sounds like you are trying to check if anything changed. The subscribe API call essentially tells Facebook to let YOU know when something changes.

Really, your issue is going to be network bandwidth and CPU, not Facebook limits.

Comment: yes, that's why i think to distribute most of the work to client side.

Answer (score 0):

The `me()` refers to the user/page ID encoded in the access token.  Lint the token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and see what id it is for.